# Why doesn't pyautogui.click() function the same as physically clicking my mouse?

Tags: python-3.x, events, focus, mouseevent, pyautogui

The allure of the pyautogui module is to simulate events like keystrokes and button clicks. The problem I've run into on multiple occasions is that it doesn't function the same as when I physically click my mouse or enter push keys on my keyboard. One example is a Citrix application, within the application hotkeys work fine, but coming from pyautogui? Forget about it. There are other applications where the mouse click stops any further functionality of the pyautogui calls, even though the program continues.
I started to title my post, "what happens when I physically click my mouse", but I got a warning to rephrase because similar questions had been down voted. If anyone can point me to some resources on this I would really appreciate it.
That said, is there a way using Python to programmatically simulate EXACTLY what happens when I physically click my mouse? Preferably something simple.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(235,711)
pyautogui.click(13,17) #doesn't move to new coordinate after clicking on certain programs
```